# Siddhi Query for Geofence Entry Detection

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi

I am trying to get Siddhi to fire events whenever it detects a flight has entered a Geofence, but can't quite figure out the correct query to do it.

I have the following input stream definition:

```
define stream GeofenceMulticasterConsumerStream ( journeyId string, geofenceId string, withinGeofence bool, timestamp long )
```

Every time I get a positional update for a flight, I get an event genereated in this stream for every Geofence in the system (there's approx 10 geofences so thought Siddhi would be capable of handling 10 * number of positional update events)

This is the query I started with:

```
define partition geofencePartition by GeofenceMulticasterConsumerStream.geofenceId;
from every a = GeofenceMulticasterConsumerStream[withinGeofence == false] ->
b = GeofenceMulticasterConsumerStream[a.journeyId == b.journeyId and b.withinGeofence == true]
within 300000
select b.journeyId, b.geofenceId, b.timestamp as timeEntered
insert into EnteredGeofenceStream
partition by geofencePartition
```

However, this gives me duplicate Geofence Entry events, as it evaluates every "a" event against every "b" event that matches (if I have 5 events that aren't in the geofence followed by one that is, I get 5 Geofence Entry events)

So I tried adding some duplicate event detection to avoid this:

```
from every a = GeofenceMulticasterConsumerStream[withinGeofence == false] ->
b = GeofenceMulticasterConsumerStream[a.journeyId == b.journeyId and b.withinGeofence == true]
within 300000
select b.journeyId, b.geofenceId, b.timestamp as timeEntered, geofences:hashEntry(b.journeyId, b.geofenceId, b.timestamp) as entryHash
insert into DuplicateEnteredGeofenceStream
partition by geofencePartition

from DuplicateEnteredGeofenceStream#window.firstUnique(entryHash)
select journeyId, geofenceId, timeEntered
insert into EnteredGeofenceStream
```

geofences:hashEntry is a function I created that generates a unique hashcode for the entry event.

However, I'm not keen on doing this, as you have to keep a record of all the unique hashes in the firstUnique window, and worried that this will create a memory leak. Seems a bit over the top as the hash will only be applicable for that point in time, and therefore I only need a firstUnique window that's valid for a couple of seconds max to check for duplicates.

I think one of the big issues I'm having is I have one stream that has multiple flights and multiple geofences being tracked within it, as all the examples I've seen have been much simplier I'm wondering if I'm trying to achieve something which isn't possible.

I'd greatly appreciate any advice with this, as I'm now running out of ideas!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to detect only the transitions a -> b, you can use 'sequences' here instead of patterns.

In Siddhi, when you use a sequence, it matches consecutive events without any other events in-between. In contrast, patterns lets other events to exist in-between.

Also in this case, since multiple flights may enter the same geofence concurrently, you'll have to partition by flight id (or journey id) instead of a geofence id (coz otherwise, there will be patterns by flights X and Y such as X_outside -> Y_outside -> X_inside -> Y_inside which will not be detected). This way, the transition of a particular flight from outside_fence -> inside_fence will always be detected properly.

So once you use the correct partitions along with sequences, you can detect transitions and there's no need to use unique windows etc here.

Refer to the [doc here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP310/Sequences) on sequences for more details.

Comment: If I partition by journeyId instead, then isn't there still the issue that events for different geofences will be passing through the partition, and therefore the sequence still won't match? A journey (flight) can be in multiple geofences at the same time.

Comment: I also read in the docs not to partition on an attribute with a high cardinality (I'll end up having hundreds of thousands of flights) although they'll only be active for the duration of a standard flight (how would Siddhi know to close partitions no longer used?)

Ideally I'd partition by journeyId and geofenceId, then a sequence would be perfect :)